# Transform Two Server Connections Into One P2P Connection

Tags: networking

I would like to create a match making server framework for online communication between multiple machines in different LANs. To keep the delays add low as possible I want to be able to create a peer to peer connection, but based on what I know about TCP you would need to forward ports to make this happen; I don't want this if it can be helped. So I was wondering if there is any way to take two separate connections to a server and turn it into one connection between the clients, without the server being involved.

TL;DR
Can I make client-server-client become client-client?

Comment: Take a look at [STUNT](http://nutss.gforge.cis.cornell.edu/stunt.php). It is made for helping connect clients through NATs. It doesn't always work (depending on both types of NATs), but I know it is used in some successful products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research it appears that I want to implement a "hole punching" system. While this will not preserve the current streams/sessions it will do what I want.